# In Vuetity 2.2 v-autocomplete how can i get selected value using $refs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I am using `v-autocomplete` component building bit complex complex component where I can not use any property from data. I am using v-model from `computed` property.

Here I am trying to use `$refs` to get the value. But I can not fetch it or can not use `$refs` properly that I have written in `scanWarehouseOuter()` method.

The `this.$refs.inputFromOutside.$el.querySelector("input").value` is working good using v-text-field not I am unable to use this in `v-autocomplete`.

The output from console.log is `value = null`.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-bind:solo="solo"
    ref="inputFromOutside"
    :items="location_list"
    prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
    v-bind:outlined="outlined"
    v-model="generatedLocation"
    append-outer-icon="mdi-tools"
    @change="scanWarehouseOuter()"
    @click:prepend="isBarcode=true"
    @click:append-outer="dialog = true"
/>

<script>
export default{
data(){
  location_list:['1-12-7', '1-12-8']
},
generatedLocation: {
  get() {}
  set(value){}
 }
},
methods:{
scanWarehouseOuter(){
  let value = this.$refs.inputFromOutside.$el.querySelector("input").value; // <--- not working
  console.log(value) // = null
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is the output of your ```scanWarehouseOuter()``` function? In the current code there no returning value for that function.

Comment: the output value is `null`. Though it can be solvable using `search.sync` function, but I am looking solution for `$ref`

Comment: Can't you get the value using just ```this.$refs.inputFromOutside.$el.value;```?